# HTML is loading faster than data in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables in `[AngularJS]`[1](https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/RRBzda). In this `[Example]`[1](https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/RRBzda) he is loading hardcoded data so it's loading quickly. But, in my case i wrote service so, data will load after some time. This mean while HTML is loading. So, initially it showing no data available after some time it showing entire 1000 records without applying pagination. Is there anything did i messed rather than that to avoid HTML loading quickly than service?

Comment: You should not mix jQuery and AngularJS yourself. A race is going on where DT and Angular are trying to update the DOM in competition with each other. You should wrap DT into directives to take care of the digest cyclus and so on, or use Angular DataTables http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/welcome where this is done already.

Comment: But, it doesn't have pdf buttons and expandable table etc,.

Comment: Yes it does, ADT support almost any DT extension. You just need to take a look at the documentation.

Comment: l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/welcome . This the documentation right

Comment: ??? It is the frontpage of the documentation, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
<div ng-if="data && data.length">
    Your dataTable here
</div>
```

around your dataTable. The variable data represents the dataSource of your table.

Or set a variable called loading to be true and have

```
<div ng-if="loading">
    ...loading or spinner gif
</div>
<div ng-if="!loading">
    Your dataTable here
</div>
```

And set loading to false when the data loads